# CanvasJS zoom default to panning with multiple charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

I enabled zoom / panning on my chart and found a post that helped me hide the zoom / panning toggle button with css.

```
.canvasjs-chart-toolbar> button:first-child {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Also to set the hidden button to panning mode.

```
var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("canvasjs-chart-toolbar");
var childElement = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
if(childElement[0].getAttribute("state") === "pan"){
  childElement[0].click();
    }
```

My problem is, when there is more than one chart on the page, the first chart's button get set to panning but the second doesn't.  Heres a JS fiddle showing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/v5d8qv3q/

Comment: Do you know if .render() is async? If so you may want to put a callback on .render() and it's just a time issue. But I don't know just my guess.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple charts in a page, there will be multiple childElement (zoom/pan buttons). So automatically clicking all childElement will solve the issue.

```
var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("canvasjs-chart-toolbar");
var childElement = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i=0;i<childElement.length;i++){
   if(childElement[i].getAttribute("state") === "pan"){
      childElement[i].click();
   }
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/n1z25mhz/).